# LINQ query to get count of records

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to retrieve some records from database along with a count, with LINQ.

```
DataTable dtByRecipe = (from tbrp in context.tblRecipeParents
    join tbrc in context.tblRecipeChilds on tbrp.RecipeParentID equals tbrc.RecipeParentID
    join tbp in context.tblProducts on tbrc.ProductID equals tbp.ProductID
    join tbps in context.tblProductSales.AsEnumerable()
    on tbp.ProductID equals tbps.ProductID
    join tbs in context.tblSales.AsEnumerable()
    on tbps.ProductSalesID equals tbs.ProductSalesID select new
    {
        tbrp.Recipe,
        tbp.ProductID,
        tbps.ProductSalesID,
        tbrp.Yield,
        Product = tbp.ProductCode + " - " + tbp.ProductDescription,
        ProductYield = tbrp.Yield,
        TotalYield = "XXX",
        Cost = "YYY"
    }).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(item => new { 
        item.Recipe,
        Count = GetCount(item.ProductID, item.ProductSalesID, context),
        item.Yield,
        Product = item.Product,
        ProductYield = item.ProductYield,
        TotalYield = "XXX",
        Cost = "YYY"
    }).OrderBy(o => o.Recipe).ToDataTable();


private int GetCount ( int ProductID, int ProductSalesID, MTBARKER_DBEntities context )
{ 
    int query = ( from tbps in context.tblProductSales
        join tbp in context.tblProducts on tbps.ProductID equals tbp.ProductID
        join tbs in context.tblSales
        on tbps.ProductSalesID equals tbs.ProductSalesID
        where tbp.ProductID == ProductID && tbps.ProductSalesID == ProductSalesID
        select tbs ).Count();

    return query;
}
```

In above query I get the expected result but since there are around 10K records in the database it consumes a lot of time to produce the result. The issue is with the following approach I have used to get the count.

```
Count = GetCount(item.ProductID, item.ProductSalesID, context),
```

Is there any productive way that I could prevent this issue?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Try to create stored procedure and call it in EF.

Comment: @malkam yes I'm using Entity Framework. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Stored Procedures is best choice for performance.Use Stored Procedures in the Entity Framework for selection and for reporting.